# Session timeout not working in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I simply want to logoff the user from the web session if they don't hit any key for certain amount of minutes. what is not right here? it's not logging off.

```
     <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="3" slidingExpiration="true"/>


</authentication>
```

Comment: Session state has nothing to do with auth cookies.

Comment: i need tohave timeout after user not hitting anything

Comment: A timeout for **what**, exactly?

Comment: we would want to end the web session for that user. after 30 minutes really.

Comment: What test are you using to show the user is not "logged off"?  In other words, how do you know it's not working?

Comment: i sit and wait for the 3 minutes

Comment: Your question is becoming a moving target by changing the code on the fly.

Comment: sorry i had left out the slidingexpiration before

Comment: And what do you expect to happen on the screen in 3 minutes?  That it will automatically redirect to another page?  I'm trying to help but you're not providing much detail.

Comment: I want it to go back to the login screen. Sorry i was not clearer.

Comment: You have to write code for that.  ASP.NET will not automatically redirect the user to a login page after timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know [this only terminates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the (in memory) session process, but does not log off the user. Instead, try to set a timeout on the [authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms timeout="5" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: i have this in but not doing  <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="5"/>
          
      
    </authentication>